# Changing the Value of an Attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting my script down to the bare bones, I have followed the example of the w3schools.com ( https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp ) for: document.getElementById(id).attribute = new value. Their example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <img id="myImage" src="smiley.gif">

<script>
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = "landscape.jpg";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is mine. I get no error messages on the Chrome console.

```
<body>

    <img id = "indexPhoto" src = 
        "newthaiimages/indexPhotos/indexPhoto_320.jpg" 
         width="320" height="474" alt="hero sepia toned photo of Thai 
         temple next to a river"/>

<script>

    document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr = 
        "newthaiimages/indexPhotos/indexPhoto_450.jpg";

</script>

</body>
```

You can see the result at http://newthaimassage.com/index3.php . Here is the script not stripped down.

```
<script>

    window.onload = function() {

       var w = window

   var x = w.innerWidth 

switch(w.innerWidth){ 

    case x <= 320:

    break;      

    case x <= 768:

        document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr ="indexPhoto_450.jpg";

    break;

    case x <= 1024:

        document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr ="indexPhoto_835.jpg"; 

    break;

    case x <= 1420:

        document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr ="indexPhoto_1000.jpg"; 

    break;

    default:

        document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr ="indexPhoto_1200.jpg"; 

}}

</script>
```

Currently I am using CSS media queries to show images by window size, but using background images I can not use CSS animation, which is my ultimate goal here. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe `.scr` should be `.src`

Comment: change `document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr` to `document.getElementById("indexPhoto").src`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, change `scr` to `src`.

Answer (score 1):

your `document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr` should be :

```
document.getElementById("indexPhoto").src
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
var ele=document.getElementById("indexPhoto");
ele.setAttribute('src',"landscape.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is syntax error, you should use `document.getElementById("indexPhoto").src` instead of `document.getElementById("indexPhoto").scr`, it is only one letter problem.